# Is there reference style documentation for Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

Is there reference style documentation for Xcode and its iOS/Cocoa Touch items, particularly the Inspector items?
For instance, to understand items such as... 
- Clears Graphics Context
- Clip Subviews
- Show Frame Rectangle
... I know I can search through the Developer's Library's guides and references, and often but not always piece together the answer, but I'm not seeing a more direct, comprehensive, and definitive path to the information.

I looked in

- Xcode>Preferences>Docs;
- Help>Search;
- the Show Quick Help Inspector;
- Command-click;
- in Window>Organizer I did find some hits but not definitive reference-style, just example code, which of course is implicit and requires inference and experimentation;
- Google;
- Stackoverflow;

Thanks

Comment: You mean the various items in the Interface Builder Inspector tabs? Most of them have tooltips, which isn't a great solution but better than nothing.

Comment: Given that all these options are just an easy way to set various properties of the object being inspected (e.g. `Clears Graphics Context` => `view.clearsContextBeforeDrawing` etc) isn't the documentation of each Class enough?

Comment: Josh, In Xcode 4.6 I'm seeing tooltips on extremely few items. I see them on the names of the inspectors themselves ("Show Identity Inspector"), and on a very few controls such as Identity Inspector>Document>Notes ("Align Left"), but not on any controls of substance or needing interpretation. I looked at loading Xcode 5, but I'm hours away.

Comment: Alladinian,
Yes, the Class Ref docs seem to be the answer. Although I've been using all of the Dev Lib doc types, I did not have a strong habit of using the Class Ref docs in particular. I would either use Command-click to look in the header files, or start at the library and try the guides & references, generally too abstract. Newbies will need one more piece of info to "connect the dots" from IB  label to reference doc: infer your way up the class hierarchy until you find the class that owns the property. In code files, the Quick Help panel is a very direct path. Thanks very much.